# When I am trying to update the map values, getting Compile Error: DML requires SObject or SObject list type: List<List<Adchrg>>

Tags: apex

```
   public void cdperiod(){
        List<Adchrg> lstRec = new List<Adchrg>();
        if(MapSlctChg != null){
            List<Adchrg> rec = MapSlctChg.get('Recurring');
            for(Adchrg chg : rec){
                 chg.amount = ((Decimal.valueOf(chg.originalchg)/ maxDays) * minDays).setScale(2);
                 lstRec.add(chg);
            }   
            MapSlctChg.put('Recurring',lstRec);
            update MapSlctChg.values();
        }
        system.debug(MapSlctChg);

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error means exactly what it says. An `update` DML statement requires a list of `Sobject` types, such as `Account`, `Contact`, etc. You are providing a `List<List<Adchrg>>`, which is not the correct type.

`Adchrg` does not appear to be an Sobject, so you cannot perform DML on it in any case. Your `Map` appears to have the type `Map<String, List<Adchrg>>`. Hence, its `values()` method returns `List<List<Adchrg>>`.